# Change color footer prestashop template defect

Tags: css, prestashop

I need to insert HTML content in the footer of prestashop and that this one has a different color. I downloaded the contentbox module and added the HTML content. But I can not change the color of that module.

My intention is that my footer has 3 different colors. I've added an example [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkr5T.png).

Comment: Can you provide more information, what element are you trying to apply style to? does it have a class or an id, have you tried !important with the id of said element.

Comment: Hello,

None, is that I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Don't get discouraged by down votes, just means that you need to research a bit more and be more specific, as the answer might already be here, see CSS3 examples and edit your css file, do you know where it is? see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_color_hex for examples

Answer (score 0):

The footer HTML code is written in the following file, you can edit it as per your requirements:

/themes/YOUR_THEME/footer.tpl